# use a variable to reference a class module VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA and I am having a problem using a variable to reference a class module.
So, I have a module MAIN with this function:

```
Public sub correr_lista ()
       For i = LBound(lista) To UBound(lista) - 1
             Call verifica (lista (i).time, lista_ficheiros(i + 1).time, lista (i).setor)
       next i
End public
```

in the same module I have this function

```
Public Sub verifica (time1 As Date, time2 As Date, V_setor As String)
  'Percorre  a lista para ver o tipo de torneira e a sua velocidade
   For a = LBound(listaon) To UBound(listaon)

        If (listaon(a).setor = V_setor) Then

            ' Pergunta à torneira porta qual a sua velocidade
            aux_velocidade(a) = V_setor.getvelocidade(listaon(a).porta)
   next a
End sub
```

I have the  class module Setor

```
Public Function getvelocidade(porta As String)

 Dim velocidade As Integer

        For a = LBound(listaSetor) To UBound(listaSetor)

                velocidade = listaSetor(a).get_velocidade(porta)
        Next i

getvelocidade = velocidade
end function
```

The listSector list is defined as:

```
Dim listaSetor () As Object
```

We have in the faucet class module

```
Public Function get_velocidade(n_porta As String)

Dim aux As Double
For i = LBound(porta) To UBound(porta)
         aux = porta(i).velocidade
Next i
 get_velocidade = aux

End Function
```

The door is defined as:

```
Dim porta(1 To 3) As tipo

Public Type tipo
   porta As String
   nome As String
   velocidade As Double
   tipo As String
End Type
```

The error that appears is invalid qualifier in the method verifica on the line :

```
aux_velocidade(a) = V_setor.getvelocidade(listaon(a).porta)
```

When the error appears it underlines the variable V_setor

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You have V_setor declared as a string.  You need to declare it as the correct object.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford i don't understand, you can explicated?

Comment: When defining or V_sector as an object, this error  'ByRef argument type mismatch ' appears on the line  Call verifica (lista (i).time, lista_ficheiros(i + 1).time, lista (i).setor) in .setor

Comment: If  `V_setor` is a string in your `verifica` subroutine parameter definition where you say `, V_setor AS String)`  then you can't do this: `V_setor.getvelocidade(listaon(a).porta)`. That subroutine has NO idea that `V_setor` is supposed to be your class, it only knows that it's a string value. At some point, either in that subroutine, or in the subroutine that is calling it you will have to define a variable as your class `Dim mySetor AS Setor` and create a new instance of your class using the `V_Setor` string so that you can do `mySetor.getvelocidade()` method.

Comment: Can I do this then? 
    
    mysetor= V_sector ?